# Adding html options to ransack predicate_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using the ransack gem with a rails 4 application, and would like to incorporate bootstrap classes into the search_form_for. This is what my select currently looks like.

```
<%= c.predicate_select ({only: [:cont, :not_cont, :eq, :not_eq, :blank, :null, :not_null]})%>
```

I've also tried passing in a second hash with html options like so (per the documentation):

```
 <%= c.predicate_select ({only: [:cont, :not_cont, :eq, :not_eq, :blank, :null, :not_null]},{class=>'form-control'})%>
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.
Anyone have any suggestions as to how to properly apply a class to the ransack predicate_select ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is weird. When I call

```
<%= c.predicate_select({only: [:cont, :not_cont]}, {class: 'my_class'}
```

I get

```
<select class="my_class" id="q_p" name="q[p]" style="display: none;">...</select>
```

You have a typo in your code sample (`...,{class=>'form_control'}`), but I suspect that is not the cause of this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response ! It was literally just the the space that I mistakenly left between "select" and "({only"
The correct syntax is :
    <%= c.predicate_select({only: [:cont, :not_cont, :eq, :not_eq, :blank, :null, :not_null]})%>


Thanks again !